# Download Images from Array

Tags: javascript

Background:

I'm new to JS (started learning this week) and I've been playing around with the Chrome Dev Tools and the Console on the following website: https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/

I went into the dev tools element selector and located the  with class="results" which is basically all of the pokemon listed.

I edited the  tag to include an id (id="poke") so I could play around with it.

The following is my code that outputs an array with all of the links to the pokemon image assets:

```
function listPokemon(){
    var pokeAssets = document.getElementById('poke').getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < pokeAssets.length; i++) {
        console.log (pokeAssets[i]);
    }
}
```

Question:

Is there a way to download all of the image assets from that array without having to do so manually using vanilla javascript?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a solution that opens new tabs for each img so you can simply tab through them and press CTRL-S on each?

Comment: You don't need to manually add an ID to the element. This works as well:  `document.querySelectorAll('.results')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')`

Comment: @Will Why would you do `document.querySelectorAll('.results')[0]` when you can just do the natural thing `document.querySelector('.results')`?

Comment: No, you can't. I don't know what is your main purpose. You're trying to learn JS or just want to download those images. If you want to learn, do other things since there still be a lot to learn. If you want to scrape those images, take a look at casperJS.

Comment: @connexo Indeed. Old habits!

Comment: If your browser supports the download property of an `<a>` tag you could use the below method. https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer would be no, javascript can't really download files onto your machine.
You don't really need JS to get the image urls, since each one is the same url preceeded with the pokemons pokedex number

`https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/004.png`
004 being the pokemon number

You could iterate this number in say a python script, which could download the images.

Answer (score 0):

One could create an array with all absolute links. Then create a temporary anchor tag `<a>` which holds the image as a source. Then use the click event to download it. However your browser needs to be [compatible](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

```
var links = [ "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/001.png", "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/002.png"]
function download(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}
var counter = 0;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) 
{ 
    download(links[i], "pokemon "+ counter);
    counter++;
}
```

First time i excuted this i was navigated to the website of pokemon.com. when i tried it in their developer console it worked (chrome version 70.xxx) I had to give consent though by pressing `Allow`: [image: First time i ran this script][image: 2nd time while on their website]